# iOS 6 rotation with an MPMoviePlayerViewController from UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, ios6, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have inherited an iOS app that has not been maintained since iOS 3 era. The app relies on a web view to display some data. One of the feature is displaying the video in a full screen mode. What the client needs is a video reacting to the device rotation but all other views should be only portrait.

I've managed to figure out all the `window.rootViewController` and `shouldAutorotate` changes. I get the app to rotate only when I want. The problem I am facing is the video rotation 'too much'.

If I rotate the device left, the video rotates by 180 degrees (it goes into upside down orientation). Rotating back to the right causes the view width to shrink by half but the orientation is correct. I am not quite sure where the problem could be.

Anyone had similar issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did have the same problem by inheriting a project. In my case, the application is navigation based, and the problem was that the main `UINavigationController`'s view was being added as a subview of an `UIViewController`'s view.

So, initially I had this code on my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
self.viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

and this on `MyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

Then I simply changed my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to this:

```
self.viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Long time, I forgot about this question. The fix to my problem was a bit different than what's explained here. But it gave me some ideas, specially the container nesting. My issues were caused by moving ios3 to ios4.3 and how the views were hacked together earlier.